# Index notation to matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, tensors, python

Assuming I have this equation in index notation and I am trying to convert it to a matrix notation:
$$
A_{ij} = B_i {(C_j + D_{ij})}^\top
$$
where $B, C \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times X}$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N \times X}$. Then I believe $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$

If it wasn't for $D$, the answer would be pretty straightforward but the summation is really throwing me off here.

Here is an example of what I'm doing with Python code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((2, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 4, (2, 3))
C = np.random.randint(0, 4, (2, 3))
D = np.random.randint(0, 4, (2, 2, 3))
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
  for j in range(C.shape[0]):
    A[i][j] = np.dot(B[i], C[j] + D[i][j])
B, C, D, A
(array([[2, 1, 3],
        [0, 0, 2]]),
 array([[2, 3, 0],
        [2, 0, 0]]),
 array([[[3, 3, 0],
         [0, 3, 1]],
 
        [[3, 1, 2],
         [0, 3, 0]]]),
 array([[16., 10.],
        [ 4.,  0.]]))
```

Is there a way to convert the above equation to a matrix notation?

Thanks!

EDIT:
So I was able to come up with this code using numpy vectorization and it seems to work all right. However, I am not sure if it is mathematically sound or how to even translate it into proper mathematical notation.

```
np.diagonal(np.dot(B, D.transpose(0, 2, 1)), axis1=0, axis2=1).T + np.dot(B, C.T)
```

Comment: It makes no sense because  $D$, according your condition, should be three-indexed

Comment: Here $A$ would be a $N \times N$ matrix where $A_{ij}$ is calculated by $B_i {(C_j + D_{ij})}^\top$ where $B_i, C_j, and D_{ij}$ would all be X- dimensional

Comment: Please share the "straightforward" answer when $D=0,\:$ that may help us determine what you're trying to do.

Comment: Without $D$ it would be $A = BC^\top$

Comment: @gotsave, what does this code do?

Comment: @janmarqz It basically just translates into code what the equation does (i.e fills up the $A$ matrix accordingly (from $B, C, D$ randomly generated). In the code $N=2, X=3$. My question is, is it possible to write my equation with matrix notation instead of index